# Kotlin - Delegation instead of inheritance in singleton

Tags: inheritance, kotlin, singleton, delegation

I would like to inherit the functionality of a Singleton class into another Singleton, but this is not possible (I understand why).

Then I decided to give it a try using delegation. The compiler is not complaining and I am going to see what happens just for curiosity!
Below you can find more info:

1. An interface `ThrottleBrake` ([implementation](https://github.com/BILLyTheLiTTle/RCCar/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/car/controllers/basic/ThrottleBrake.kt))
2. A singleton `ThrottleBrakeImpl` which extends the interface above ([implementation](https://github.com/BILLyTheLiTTle/RCCar/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/car/controllers/basic/ThrottleBrakeImpl.kt))
3. Another singleton `ElectronicThrottleBrakeImpl` which uses both of the above as it is shown in the next code snippet:

   ```
   object ElectronicThrottleBrakeImpl: ThrottleBrake by ThrottleBrakeImpl {

   override fun throttle(direction: String, value: Int): String {
       return ThrottleBrakeImpl.throttle(direction, value)
   }}
   ```

But I would like to know if this is a good practice or not. Should I continue the project like this or should I find a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I use a similar constellation to have something like extendable enums.

```
enum class NonExtendable {
  A, B
}
```

becomes then:

```
object Extendables {
  object A : Extendable by ExtendableImpl()
  object B : Extendable by ExtendableImpl()
}

interface Extendable

class ExtendableImpl : Extendable
```

and I am now able to deliver an additional ~enum value `C` just as follows:

```
object C : Extendable by ExtendableImpl()
```

and I think also lots of others documented this as extendable enums, but I couldn't find a good source (I am behind a firewall) to support it as good practice though ;-)

I wonder why you require singletons in the first place. But if they are like enums then I would say the practice is definitely OK ;-) (otherwise I put myself into trouble)

Comment: I have never thought that for enums! It looks good! I will search for these "extendable enums" to get feedback cuz they look like, a lot, what I have. The only difference I found is that I don't use any `class`, just `object`s.

Comment: Can you tell me why you are using that many `object`s in the first place? While it probably will work, it doesn't really feel good to me. You can achieve the same using classes themselves which have a lot of benefits over objects.

Comment: This is a Raspberry Pi project, and I want each object to handle one or many unique pins. Using classes, I should pass around a reference of a single object 
 to control the pins. With Singletons I feel safer that no other instance could control the pins.

Comment: Still, I recommend you to use classes and instances. Using `object` in that case might lead to faster resutls but will be a pain to refactor later on if you want to reuse or extend your classes. Use `object` only if it really is a singleton. `object` itself is by no means safer to use then instances of classes. It rather suggests a false sense of safety